# Strange Default Method behavior with different Java versions

Tags: java, interface, abstract-methods, default-method, java-bridge-method

Let's say I have the following class hierarchy:

```
interface Collection<E>
{
    Collection<E> $plus(E element)
}

interface MutableCollection<E> extends Collection<E>
{
    @Override
    MutableCollection<E> $plus(E element)
}

interface Set<E> extends Collection<E>
{
    @Override
    Set<E> $plus(E element)
}

interface MutableSet<E> extends Set<E>, MutableCollection<E>
{
    @Override
    default MutableSet<E> $plus(E element)
    {
        // ... implementation
    }
}

abstract class AbstractArraySet<E> implements Set<E>
{
    // ... no $plus(...) implementation
}

class ArraySet<E> extends AbstractArraySet<E> implements MutableSet<E>
{
    // ... no $plus(...) implementation
}
```

As you can see, only the `MutableSet` class provides an implementation for the `$plus` method. In a Test case, I am calling this method on an instance of type `ArraySet`. The Test always passes in the CI environment, while it always fails with an `AbstractMethodError` on my local environment. In both cases, I am using Gradle (2.7).

---

## The Error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method dyvil/collection/mutable/ArraySet.$plus(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ldyvil/collection/Collection; is abstract

    at dyvil.collection.mutable.ArraySet.$plus(ArraySet.java)
    at dyvil.tests.CollectionTests.testCollection(CollectionTests.java:99)
    at ...
```

---

## [Test Code](https://github.com/Dyvil/Dyvil/blob/v0.16.0/src/test/dyvil/tests/CollectionTests.java#L99):

```
testCollection(new ArraySet());

public void testCollection(Collection collection)
{
    assertEquals(mutable.$plus("newElement"), collection.$plus("newElement"));
}
```

---

## `java -version` output:

- [CI](https://drone.io/github.com/Dyvil/Dyvil/523) (where it works):

  ```
  java version "1.8.0"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
  ```
- Local (where it fails):

  ```
  java version "1.8.0_71"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)
  ```

---

I am expecting this to be some sort of `javac` bug, where the compiler fails to add all required bridge methods (the code compiles without any warnings or errors). In IntelliJ IDEA, the problem occurs both using `javac` and the Eclipse Compiler.

Comment: Are you presenting what you already proved to be the minimal setup to reproduce the error? There are a lot of interfaces here, if it can't be demostrated with fewer then the problem looks quite complex.

Comment: Decompile the `MutableSet.class` that is executed in runtime in your local environment. Is there a default method there?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic, yes, there are bridge methods for all super-interface `$plus` methods. There are no bridge methods in the `ArraySet` class, though.

Comment: No repro on "Netbeans with jdk1.8.0_65"

Comment: What is your project structure? Is the code in which you do assertions in the same jar as `MutableSet`?

Comment: I'd suggest reproducing without the dollar sign in the method name.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic check the Test Code link - it's all in the same project.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the problem also occurs for methods with normal named like `mapped`, so this can't be the problem.

Comment: And does it occur in any setting simpler than yours? If this is a compiler bug, it will be crucial to exactly delineate the circumstances where it occurs.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I guess you could remove the `Collection` layer. I am not sure though, since that is what the error talks about. Will test as soon as I have access to my dev environment.

Comment: Ok, did you decompile the `.class` file or you just assumed that default method is there because you see it in the source (`.java`) file?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I checked it with `javap`

Comment: Locally, the problem manifests from IDEA only, or can you reproduce with plain `javac` on command line? (I realize you can't answer this at the moment)

Comment: I set it up in IDEA, with JDK 1.8.0_71, and couldn't reproduce.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I haven't tested it with javac, but I can reproduce it with Gradle on my local env. At the very least, you should be able to reproduce this problem by cloning the [repo](https://github.com/Dyvil/Dyvil) and running `gradle build test`.

Comment: Did it: `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`

Comment: Turns out doing a full `clean` and rebuild fixed the problem for me as well. Nevertheless, there must have been a bug involved at some point that caused the faulty binaries. Thanks for you efforts, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answer is made based on author's comment above: problem was solved):

Doing a full clean and rebuild fixed the problem as well.

Nevertheless, there must have been a bug involved at some point that caused the faulty binaries.